# newly added files not being discovered by src in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I first write all files in src to a new folder. but when I try to use a second src the folder is empty. I guess there is some cache issue maybe??

```
src(project + "/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(rename({
        prefix: "_"
    }))
    .pipe(dest(tempPath));

return src(tempPath + "/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(debug())
```

Comment: How about handling errors on these pipes?

Comment: @matcheek how is that related to my issue?

Comment: I don't think you know what your issue is if you don't handle exceptions

Comment: the issue is that newly added files don't appear before the task is run again

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return src(project + "/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(rename({
        prefix: "_"
    }))
    .pipe(dest(tempPath))

    // src(tempPath + "/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(debug());

    // .pipe(do stuff with tempPath + "/**/*.scss" files));
```

This works because `gulp.dest` returns the stream.  See [gulp.dest returns](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest#returns).  And because you appear to be using the same stream and not modifying it.

If you wanted to work on a subset of that stream you could use something like [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter).  To expand on the stream, try [gulp-add-src](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src).